# Contingency Tables for all columns in a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe with binary data (all factors) with the following structure:

**Data:**

```
convert tv radio print
0       1  1     0
1       0  1     1
0       0  0     0
1       0  0     1
```

**Question:**

I want to have the proportion of convert==1 in percentage by each column of the dataframe, so imagine there are 100 rows, with 40 cases where convert == '1', then the proportion shown as rows (#tv==1/#convert==1)=0.98 and (#tv==0/#convert==1)=0.02

**Expected Outcome:**

```
value tv   radio print
0     0.02 0.42  0.70
1     0.98 0.58  0.30
```

**Approach so far:**

I am using prop.table inside a for loop, but it is not as elegant as I think is possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach: Apply `table()` across the columns, then divide by the number of entries.

```
# making some junk data

df <- data.frame(
  convert = rbinom(100, 1, 0.4), 
  tv = rbinom(100, 1, 0.3),
  radio = rbinom(100, 1, 0.2),
  print = rbinom(100, 1, 0.4)
)

apply(df[df$convert == 1, -1], 2, table) / sum(df$convert == 1)
```

The column condition of -1 is to remove the first column (the trivial `convert` column) from the table.

Comment: I *think* I have correctly interpreted what you want to do? Please let me know if I missed the mark. This should give the relative proportions of 1 and 0 within each column, counting only those rows for which `convert == 1`.

Answer (score 1):

We can also use `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df %>% 
   filter(convert == 1) %>%  
   select(-1) %>% 
   map_dfc(~ table(.)/length(.))
```